# How to fix "id -u" returning 0 into my variable for if statement?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to put the result of "id -u $1" into a variable in order to verify it with an if statement but it seems like it's returning 0 into my variable even tho I've checked it and it's supposed to be 1008.Is it because the username is taken from the argument of the script?

```
UID=`id -u $1`
LOCK=`usermod -L $1`

if test $UID -lt 500;then

        echo "impossible to lock user"

else

        $LOCK;

fi
```

Comment: Use lowercase letters for your own variable names to avoid colliding with existing environment variables.

Comment: See output of `declare -p UID`. Variable UID is a read-only (`-r`) variable. See `help declare`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you use system variable in your script and try to change it.
instead of `UID` try to use `UID1` (for example) as variable name. And your script will be something like:

```
UID1=`id -u $1`
LOCK=`usermod -L $1`

if test $UID1 -lt 500;then
        echo "impossible to lock user"
else
        $LOCK;
fi
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on it for hours.